# Find feet-waist size while having a full body size

Tags: ratio

Must be a weird question, I was also confused to which community I should post this question.

A question about human's body.

I want to find a feet to waist size and a waist to head size in CM.
I have a body height and it's 172 CM.

I read an article on wikipedia that the feet-waist ratio is 0.35-0.41 that mean that the torso is 59% to 65% of the 172 CM right?

So, the question is how do I find the feet-waist size using the waist ratio including the error in calculations (in CM and in percentage)?

Answer (score 1):

Te feet to waist size is at least $0.35$ and at most $0.41$, which means that the distance from your feet to your waist ie at least $0.35\cdot 172\mathrm{cm}$ and at most $0.41\cdot172\mathrm{cm}.$

In other words, it's $60.12\mathrm{cm} - 70.52\mathrm{cm}$

Comment: Yeah right, I did the math. The problem is the error in calculations. I need an equation to calculate the error. Like +/- 10cm or something. But more "theoretical" not just +/- #. Thank you.